# Pros and cons of binary representation in a genetic algorithm

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm

I'm solving problem of making teams of players for some game, using genetic algorithm.

Having `pool` of players to split, I represent individual from population as a row of `teams`, where each `team` is some list or an array of number of players in `pool`. I translate each number to the binary encode, as if it was in "original" genetic algo. But now I start to think of advantages and disadvantages of binary representation of the individuals.

My thoughts were that I can use very common `mutation` and `crossover` frameworks: just change bits and change tails, accordingly. But I am able to do it with just integer numbers, simply using some manual `mutation` function.

So, the question is: what are the benefits and drawbacks of the binary/integer-valued representation? What is most "true" way to use GA?

I checked original book by author of GA, John Holland, and there he uses binary representation, but I haven't found (yet probably) information about what representation fits best.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33518171/9850300) answer shown one drawback whilst using float numbers: after crossover two parents could move far away from each other. But in my case I don't need to use float numbers.